# Basic Haskell Recursive Function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a basic recursive function that calculates the alternating sum of a list of numbers (`[1, 2, 3] -> 1 - 2 + 3`). I am fairly new to Haskell, so I have just been toying around with this problem with little success. Below is my most recent attempt. It works with lists of up to length two.

```
alternateSum [] = 0
alternateSum (p:ps) = if odd (length ps) then
                         p - alternateSum ps
                      else 
                         p + alternateSum ps
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok - you somehow have to carry the *sign* with you so the obvious solution is to do it with an argument (and then add a version that fixes this argument for the first call):

```
alternateSum' :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
alternateSum' _ []     = 0
alternateSum' f (h:tl) = f * h + alternateSum' (-f) tl

alternateSum :: [Integer] -> Integer
alternateSum ns = alternateSum' 1 ns
```

which will yield what you want:

```
λ> alternateSum [1,2,3]
2
```

---

your version has the problem that for the first version (assuming `[1,2,3]`) `ps` will have length `2` which is of course *even* but for `[1,2]` it will have length `1` (*odd*) and your version would be right ... that's where you are in trouble - your sign depends on the length instead of the position

---

Here is a fun version you can try to figure out:

```
alternateSum :: [Integer] -> Integer
alternateSum ns = sum $ zipWith ($) (cycle [id,negate]) ns
```

this one will rewrite the list `[1,2,3]` first into `[1,(-2),3]` and then `sum` the list ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How does alternateSum' have access to the list passed to alternateSum? Sorry if this is a basic question, still learning.

Comment: `alternateSum` passes it's input to `alternateSum'` - I just eta-reduced the last parameter - sorry will fix this (probably to much for beginners)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive alternative:

```
alternateSum :: [Integer] -> Integer
alternateSum xs = go False 0 xs
--            Odd     Accumul    Tail
  where go :: Bool -> Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
        go _ acc [] = acc
        go False acc (x:xs) = go True  (acc + x) xs
        go True  acc (x:xs) = go False (acc - x) xs
```

I'm not a super expert, just trying.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - 5))) = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5
```

So you can write

```
alternateSum = foldr (-) 0
```

Nice, but inefficient. Dual and more efficient:

```
import Data.List

alternateSum = foldl' (flip (-)) 0 . reverse
```

But a direct tail recursive solution should be better anyway.